# Bootstrap-Vue Modal reopens everytime except in ESC

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I am currently writing a Vue component for a project.
I encountered a Problem where a Bootstrap-Vue modal will re open again instead of closing.
I am using Vue.js in Version 2.6.10 and Bootstrap 4.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-button v-b-modal.rating-modal @click="showModal()">
            Click me
            <b-modal ref="rating-modal" no-close-on-backdrop centered title="Rate" class="rating-modal" @ok="hideModal" @cancel="hideModal" @close="hideModal">
                <div>
                    Content of the modal...
                </div>
            </b-modal>
        </b-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "Rating",
        components: {
            ,
        },
        methods: {
            showModal() {
                this.$refs['rating-modal'].show();
            },
            hideModal() {
                this.$refs['rating-modal'].hide();
            },
        }
    }
    ;
</script>
```

I expect it to close when I hit either cancel, ok or the cross in the header.

Comment: Did you check if your methods are being called by using console?

Comment: Yeah i checked it, but I already resolved my issue. Still thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the Issue by myself. All I had to do is to move the b-modal tag out of the b-button tag like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-button v-b-modal.rating-modal @click="showModal()">
            Click me
        </b-button>
        <b-modal ref="rating-modal" no-close-on-backdrop centered title="Rate" class="rating-modal" @ok="hideModal" @cancel="hideModal" @close="hideModal">
            <div>
                Content of the modal...
            </div>
        </b-modal>
    </div>
</template>
```